# Python - Selecting elements of list b containing elements of list a

Tags: python, list

There is a_list and b_list. We are in the process of sorting out only the b_list elements that contain elements of a_list.

```
a = ["Banana", "Orange", "Almond", "Kiwi", "Cabbage"]
b = [["Banana", "Pencil", "Water Bucket"], ["Orange", "Computer", "Printer"], ["Snail", "Cotton Swab", "Sweet Potato"]]
c = []
```

If the first element of list in b_list matches an element of list a_, this list element is put into c_list.So the desired result is

```
c = [["Banana", "Pencil", "Water Bucket"], ["Orange", "Computer", "Printer"]]
```

I've searched several posts, but couldn't find an exact match, so I'm leaving a question. help

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: `[l for l in b if any(i in a for i in l)]`

Comment: Olvin Roght-Perfect. thank you I deleted the post and tried to write it again, but this solved it.

Comment: @anfwkdrn that expression matches *any* element of the list in `b_list`: did you want to match specifically on "the first element of list in `b_list`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your answer

```
for i in b:
    if i[0] in a:
        c.append(i)
```

Comment: @tobias_k OP said "If the **first** element of list in b_list..."

Comment: @slothrop Yes, just saw the sentence. Beginning of question sounds different.

Answer (score 3):

```
c =[i for i in b if i[0] in a]
```

Comment: OP is looking for specifically a match on "the **first** element of list in b_list..."

Comment: Oh! missed that. editing.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [i for i in range(1, 10)]
b = [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [10, 100, 1000]]
c = []

for sublist in b:
    if sublist[0] in a:
        c.append(sublist)

>>> c
[[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200]]
```